# Слова "разграбление" и "смешение" могут быть употреблены во мн. ч.?

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

> Но и после веков упадка – периода раннего Средневековья – Рим вновь
>   завоюет господство. Великое переселение народов (IV–VII вв.) –
>   наводнение Европы отсталыми племенами, бесконечная бойня, которая
>   длится и длится в провинциях, **разграбления Рима, смешения культур,
>   языков и культов**, страшнейшие моровые поветрия, зародившиеся на
>   болотах Египта и захватившие земли павшей державы, словно приостановят
>   ход мировой истории…

Comment: Моровые поветрия (если это о летающих летальных микробах) - **о**хватили (_захватывают_ с краёв внутрь чего-то).

Comment: @Alex_ander   Микробы захватили римские земли! Вы историю разве не читали?  :))

Comment: А впрочем.. Есть один пример в Нацкопусе: Сегодня эпидемия уже **захватила** обширные области в Южной Америке ― 125 стран. [Елена Кудрявцева, Элионора Самотаева. Медицина // «Огонек», 2013]

Comment: Это возможно только в одном случае: в значении "захватить, задеть, зацепить (попутно) примыкающие к уже _охваченным той же эпидемией_ территории". Если даже принять "захват, осуществлённый злыми микробами", то поветрия на это неспособны, он "охватывают" страны и геогр. территории.  :)

Comment: Сашко, уже исправила захват на охват; текст улетел к автору.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рим грабили не раз. Если это так уж важно подчеркнуть, то пусть будут  *разграбления*.  А вот происходившее смешение культур вряд ли можно разделить на первое, второе и т.д. — *смешение* было одно (процесс).

Поветрия **зарождавшиеся** (неоднократно) и **охватывавшие** (неоднократно).

Или в наст. вр.: **зарождающиеся** и **охватывающие**, это лучше сочетается с буд. вр. "приостановят".

И почему моровые поветрия сидят в списке, касающемся переселения народов? Разве из Египта переселялись?

Структура предложения должна бы быть такой:

*Великое переселение — то да се — приостановило ход истории.*

Или так:

Великое переселение народов (IV–VII вв.) **и все, что сним связано,** – первое, второе, третье, — всё это словно приостановит ход мировой истории…

Comment: А не получится так, что культуры с языками и культами смешали?

Comment: Разумный читатель разберется. Я бы не придирался именно к этому.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.

Comment: @grizzly Не надо благодарить. Это всего лишь мнение.

Answer (score 1):

Структура предложения не совсем ясна, поэтому внесены изменения:

**Великое переселение народов (IV–VII вв.)** – наводнение Европы отсталыми племенами, бесконечная бойня, которая длится и длится в провинциях, разграбления Рима, смешение культур, языков и культов, страшнейшие моровые поветрия, зародившиеся на болотах Египта и захватившие земли павшей державы, – **всё это словно приостановит ход мировой истории…**

Поясняющая **вставка** выделена тире.

Comment: (1) Если бы не первая часть, то я бы приветствовал эту форму (перечисление, тире, "все это"). (2) Почему моровые поветрия сидят  в списке, касающемся переселения народов? Из Египата переселялись?

Comment: Ну да, вместе с египтянами. Разве переселение народов не могло способствовать  распространению болезней?

Comment: Я плохой знаток истории, но мне кажется, народы переселялись из Европы, а не из Египта.

Comment: Вообще-то говоря,  "по теме" было бы не о происхождении микробов писать, а о том, что их народы перенесли.

Comment: М_Г, пишет историк искусства; Жасмин, почему не закрыта запятая *перед* тире?

Comment: Может, он и эпидемиолог? Знает, в какой земле микробы родились и как в Рим попали?

Comment: @Jasmin - ***почему не закрыта запятая ПЕРЕД тире?***

Comment: Надо, конечно,  закрыть оборот, сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Как вам такое построение: Великое переселение народов (IV–VII вв.) **и все, что с ним связано,** – первое, второе, третье, — всё это словно приостановит ход мировой истории... – М_Г 1 час назад

Comment: Грамматика нормальная,  но стандартная. Кроме того, объем предложения увеличился, а информации не прибавилось, а это сейчас не приветствуется и не в стиле автора.